# NSDateFormatter is giving one year ahead date for 12/30/2012 and for 12/31/2012

Tags: objective-c

I am new to the field. This question may be silly.

`NSDateFormatter` is giving one year ahead date for 12/30/2012 and for 12/31/2012. For 12/30/2013 and 12/31/2013 it will also push the year out to 2014.

My code is:

```
 -(NSString*)getDateOrTime:(NSDate *)inDate formatter:(NSString *)lformat
 {
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter setDateFormat:lformat];//@"MMM-dd-yyyy"];
     NSString *currentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:inDate];// here it is giving wrong    date
     // it is happening for only mentioned specific dates only
     [formatter release];

     return currentDate;
 }
```

How can I get it to give me the right date?

Comment: Can you show us how you compose your `inDate`? The only thing i can imagine at this point what happens is that your date has some kind of a massive timezone offset, which makes the day appear "tomorrow".

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Please tell me if you find out how to to.

Comment: check this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627993/date-formater-giving-wrong-date-when-converting-to-string-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

As you are not giving the formatter informations about the timezone, the NSDateFormatter assume the dates as GMT-times. You need to set the correct timezone — either to the dateFormatter or add it to the string.. There are hundreds of post about this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: sure it does — if the given date is the last day of a year (as shown by OP)

Comment: Although it is adding a year, it's not changing to jan 1.

Comment: The reason I'm concerned is that I got the same problem here around the start of the new year. All worked well before, but for example 2013-01-05 becomes 2014-01-05 when making date of a string. Wierd how it's selective with which dates to do that. Not hijacking the thread, just adding coments...

Answer (score -1):

The format should be as follows.

The supplied date format should be `@"MM-dd-yyyy"`

```
  [formatter setDateFormat:lformat];//@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
```

You have to use `MM` only as per the date format.