# Date formatter giving wrong date when converting to string Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm converting a date to text to display in a text box and it converts fine. The 29,30 and 31 December 2013 gets converted to 2014 and 29,30 and 31 December 2014 gets converted to 2015.

This is my code to convert the date to text

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM YYYY"];
self.pickupDateTextField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self.datePicker date]];
NSLog(@"%@ %@",self.datePicker.date,self.pickupDateTextField.text);
```

This is what the `NSLog` is printing.

```
2013-12-29 06:58:14 +0000 29 Dec 2014
```

Comment: Show the Code for **[self.datePicker date]**

Comment: Have you tried the answer I mentioned below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct date formatter string is as below:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
```

It should have small "yyyy" and not the capital "YYYY".